# Is this Grazon manure contamination or Tomato Curly-Top Virus from leafhopper?

Tags: tomatoes, virus

It started a few days ago. I see these signs, the leaves twist and curl. 8 out of 10 plants have it. All herbs, basil, rosemary, oregano are not affected. I have been watering normally. I also have been adding potassium, calcium, and blood meal, can too much of this cause this problem? I place plastic over the soil to keep it cool. My compost consists of Maryland clay soil mixed with a lot of horse manure (This may have been tainted with grazon), grass, and leaves. My plant hardiness zone is 7a. The temperature here lately is between 50 and 80 degrees. I water by drip line and by hand at times.

There is a photo in the link below. The tomato leaves here look just like mine. Would you recommend removing all of the soil and starting over? I have a raised bed and it is 68 ft.².

https://www.thesurvivalgardener.com/dealing-with-grazon-contamination/

The photos below are my plants.

[image]

[image]

[image]